# Trying to use css-grid but not all of the elements seem to be going in the right spot

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the grid area template with correct formating, but for some reason, when I add an element and assign it's grid-area, it goes into the next available space in the column. eg: supposed to be middle column bottom row, but instead showed up on the middle column a space away from the privious element. (example shown in code) Also, the spacing is not working eg: 3fr is the same size as a 1fr. (This is in code pen)
**fixed this problem in comments**

New problem: the numbers are surrounding everything, why?

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(90, 250, 190);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.container {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  grid-template-columns: 30px 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 3fr 3fr 1fr 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "description description description" "1 name nameinput"
 "2 email emailinput" 
"3 age ageinput"
 "4 redblueoryellow redblueoryellowinput"
 "5 mixedwith mixedwithinput"
 "6 lighterordarkerdropdown lighterordarkerdropdowninput" 
"7 radiobuttons radiobuttonsinput" 
"8 questionsorcomments questionsorcommentsinput"
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.\31 {
  grid-area: \31;
}

.\32 {
  grid-area: \32;
}

.\33 {
  grid-area: \33;
}

.\34 {
  grid-area: \34;
}

.\35 {
  grid-area: \35;
}

.\36 {
  grid-area: \36;
}

.\37 {
  grid-area: \37;
}

.\38 {
  grid-area: \38;
}

.name {
  grid-area: name;
}

.email {
  grid-area: email;
}

.questionsorcomments {
  grid-area: questionsorcomments;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="description" class="description">
    What is your favorite color?
  </p>
    <p class="1">1.</p>
    <p class="2">2.</p>
    <p class="3">3.</p>
    <p class="4">4.</p>
    <p class="5">5.</p>
    <p class="6">6.</p>
    <p class="7">7.</p>
    <p class="8">8.</p>
    <p class="name">What is your name?</p>
    <p class="email">What is your email?</p>
    <p class="questionsorcomments"> Any questions or comments?</p>
</div>
```

The numbers are supposed to be running down the side. If you want a link to the full codepen then here it is:     https://codepen.io/Homburg_Molly/pen/arbzeN

Comment: grid properties work on the direct child elements of the *grid container* - you have wrapped them into containers - eg the `questionsorcomments` is not a *grid child* but inside another `questions` wrapper... also please add your full code into the question, thanks!

Comment: you can put only the `container` and its css into a *snippet* in the question to create a demo that replicates the issue... try adding a snippet, let me know if you face issues...

Comment: see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVGVNg - removed all code that doesn't relate to your problem. this can be converted into a snippet and added to the question :)

Comment: Also, I thought that what I put in my question was all the related code. Is there something else I should put in there to make it more clear?

Comment: the css is there, but the full html is not there along with the `container` div... want me edit the question and create a snippet for you?

Comment: Did that fix it?

Comment: almost, will create a snippet out of the code

Comment: regarding the query - adding `grid-area: 1` on the element `.1` for instance will not work because it is not a direct child of `container` (*grid container*) but inside `numbers` - grid properties work on direct child elements only...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. div numbers is not needed anyways. Thank you for helping me. I will try to fix this.

Comment: sure, update it here if you face issues, thank you :)

Comment: the class names and grid-area names are starting with numbers. when identifiers start with number you have to prefix unicode \3 see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgOEaB

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Can I turn your comments into an answer or do you want to?

Comment: revert the edit to the question to the original one (you don't need to add the answer to the question) and I'd turn it into an answer, thank you :)